# Date diff in days is returning the same value to different dates

Tags: java, datetime

I have a code that give me the difference in days from today to a especific date.

But I have a limit: passing the date: 2018-10-21, its returning the difference-1 day.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    diffInDays("2018-10-21T11:22:05.874-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]"); // 968 : OK!
    diffInDays("2018-10-22T11:22:05.874-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]"); // 968 <- NOK! Should be: 969
}

public static void diffInDays(String date){
    ZonedDateTime parsedDate = java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
    ZonedDateTime parseDateTruncateToDays = parsedDate.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    ZonedDateTime currentDateZonedDateTime = java.time.ZonedDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    long diffInDays = java.time.Duration.between(currentDateZonedDateTime, parseDateTruncateToDays).toDays();
    System.out.println(diffInDays);
}
```

Do you have any ideia of the reason of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the problem.

It's because daylight saving time.
When you have a date, like:

```
2018-10-22T11:22:05.874-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
```

and you execute:

```
ZonedDateTime parseDateTruncateToDays = parsedDate.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

It will convert to:2018-10-22**T01:00:00.000**-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

At the moment the code will check the date diff, the time (disconsidering the daylight saving time) will get at: **2018-10-21T00:00:00.000**-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

Thats why its always returning a -1 day.

To fix it, just change the truncatedTO to:

```
ZonedDateTime parseDateTruncateToDays = parsedDate.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
```

Then it will start considering the hour for calculating :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it didn't work - possibly because Duration ignored DST and there is a time change on the 21st or 22nd of October 18.

It would make more sense to use:

```
return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(currentDateZonedDateTime, parseDateTruncateToDays);
```